# Could anyone explain me the meaning of the sentence?

Tags: meaning, sentence, literature

I can't understand the sentence in "The Innocence of Father Brown". Could anybody explain the meaning of it?

> It was he who had kept up an unaccountable and close correspondence with a young lady whose whole letter-bag was intercepted, by the extraordinary trick of photographing his messages infinitesimally small upon the slides of a microscope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially it means that there is a man who has managed to maintain an undetected correspondence with a young lady despite her letters being intercepted (by an unnamed agent/agency). He manages to do so by hiding his messages in very small writing (or type) upon a microscope slide, which are (presumably) sent along with the letters. We have to assume that she's aware of this and uses a microscope to read them.